# Generating a DataFrame from a list of rows line by line

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a highly irregular text file that I am trying create a Pandas DataFrame from. After lots of juggling (deleting irregular, lines, variable headers etc.) I got to a point where I have parsed each line as needed, but I am having trouble in converting it into a DataFrame. Please note that each line is of variable lengths and the number of elements in each line can be different.

**Input**

```
15.2'   4.3'  16.9'   4.0', GVW kips= 70.6,  9.5, 14.5, 14.1, 15.8, 16.7
3.2'   10.0'  , GVW kips= 30.2,  9.5, 11.3, 12.0
```

**Desired Output DataFrame** (note that `'` characters I have to get rid of, and the first number after `GWV kips=` not included in the DataFrame)

```
S1    S2    S3    S4    S5   W1    W2    W3    W4    W5    W6
15.2  4.3   16.9  4.0   Nan  9.5   14.5  14.1  15.8  16.7  Nan
3.2   10.0  Nan   Nan   Nan  30.2  9.5   11.3  12.0  Nan   Nan
```

To parse one line

```
my_string = r"15.2'   4.3'  16.9'   4.0', GVW kips= 70.6,  9.5, 14.5, 14.1, 15.8, 16.7"
my_list = my_string.split("'") #get rid of " ' " characters
my_list = [l.split(',') for l in ','.join(my_list).split(' GVW kips= ')] # split the list into two parts one for "S" columns one for "W" columns
my_list = [list(filter(None, lst)) for lst in my_list] # get rid of '' empty strings
my_list = [[float(j) for j in i] for i in my_list] # convert everything to floats
my_list[1].pop(0) # get rid of first element after GVW kips=
```

this gives me the following two lists:

```
[[15.2, 4.3, 16.9, 4.0], [9.5, 14.5, 14.1, 15.8, 16.7]]
```

at this point I got stuck when converting these 2 lists, first one for columns `S1` to `S5`, and the other for columns `W1` to `W6`, into a DataFrame where missing elements should be shown with NaNs. And the operation so far is only for one line. I need to do the same for more than 1,000,000 lines.

I think I can create Series lists named `W1` through `W6` and `S1` through `S5`, then append the values line by line. Then convert everything to a DataFrame when all Series are ready. The problem is in reality I have 30 W and 29 S columns, this would require me to maintain 59 lists for the whole run, which does not sound meaningful...

Is there a better way to build a DataFrame by reading a text file line by line, and using the output two lists for each line, where each line may be of different lengths?

Thanks!

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html might be able to help. Look into read_csv function.

Answer (score 0):

This works

1. one of the simplest ways to understand how I've build dictionary is get familiar with various options of data frame `to_dict()` formats
2. I really saw a simple pattern, string is in two parts *S* and *W* delimited by a constant string.  So use a `re` to get the two parts
3. use `zip` to classify and make building `dict` keys simple

```
import re, io
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
    
inp = """15.2'   4.3'  16.9'   4.0', GVW kips= 70.6,  9.5, 14.5, 14.1, 15.8, 16.7
3.2'   10.0'  , GVW kips= 30.2,  9.5, 11.3, 12.0"""

# remove unwanted spaces and quotes
inp = inp.replace("'","").replace(",","")

d = {r:{f"{k}{c+1}":vv
  # tokenise into S & W with "GVW kips=" being delimter
  for k,v in zip(["S","W"], re.findall("^([\d. ]*)GVW kips= ([\d. ]*)$", s)[0])
  # use re.split so multiple spaces are treated as one
  for c, vv in enumerate(re.split("[ ]+", str(v)))
 } 
 for r, s in enumerate(inp.split("\n"))}

pd.DataFrame(d).T.replace({"":np.nan})
```

**output**

```
   S1    S2    S3   S4  S5    W1   W2    W3    W4    W5    W6
 15.2   4.3  16.9  4.0 NaN  70.6  9.5  14.5  14.1  15.8  16.7
  3.2  10.0   NaN  NaN NaN  30.2  9.5  11.3  12.0   NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Add NaN to satisfy the required number of columns. It is converted into a data frame after completing a million rows in a loop process. This method will be faster and more efficient.

```
s = 5
for i in range(s - len(my_list[0])):
    my_list[0].append(np.NaN)

w = 6
for i in range(w - len(my_list[1])):
    my_list[1].append(np.NaN)

new = pd.DataFrame(index=[], columns=[])
new = pd.concat([new, pd.Series(sum(my_list,[])).to_frame().T], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
cols = ['S1','S2','S3','S4','S5','W1','W2','W3','W4','W5','W6']
new.columns = cols
new
S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  W1  W2  W3  W4  W5  W6
0   15.2    4.3 16.9    4.0 NaN 9.5 14.5    14.1    15.8    16.7    NaN
```